# Confused about variable binding

Tags: javascript

I was researching var vs. let and I stumbled upon a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) containing this code

```
var funcs = [];
// let's create 3 functions
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // and store them in funcs
  funcs[i] = function() {
    // each should log its value.
    console.log("My value: " + i);
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  // and now let's run each one to see
  funcs[j]();
}
```

The output confused me, it was

> My value: 3
> My value: 3
> My value: 3

instead of

> My value: 0
> My value: 1
> My value: 2

The top answer for this question says

> Well, the problem is that the variable `i`, within each of your anonymous functions, is bound to the same variable outside of the function.

Why is this? What is happening in the JavaScript engine that causes this?

Comment: `console.log("My value: " + i)` is only evaluated when the function is called. And... you happen to call it when the first loop is over and `i` is 3. Since the variable is global, all your functions refer to the same `i`

Comment: `var i` creates **one** variable instance which is global, so it will be settled to 3 when the first loop has finished. However if you would do `for (let i =......`, then the loop body gets a new `i` instance with block scope for each iteration, and then it will work as you expected.

Comment: The answers in that question give numerous explanations/ solutions

Comment: I've slightly re-written your snippet to hopefully provide you with a better picture of what actually happens. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/84ed632cf114367c5f0e45a195e89faf